# Check for content of Stack directive in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I used the `stack()` to fetch the `push()`ed values in my template:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    @stack('ready_script')
});
</script>
```

But I wanted to check if something `push()`ed already then put the `<script>` and other codes.

Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no directive in laravel for @stack checking.
You need to define one custom directive

See "Extending Blade" in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#extending-blade)

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        // ...

        Blade::directive('hasStack', function ($expression){
            return "<?php if (! empty(trim(\$__env->yieldPushContent($expression)))): ?>";
        });
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

After, in your blade file:

```
@hasStack('ready_script')
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    @stack('ready_script')
});
</script>
@endif
```